# JS: How to remove white spaces only from inside of string

Tags: javascript, string, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I need in javascript language remove white spaces from inside of string, only. Left and right sides can have that spaces. I don't finding solution...

Maybe is some native function? Or sombedy have some regex?

I only have:

```
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

But it removes white spaces from sides too.

I want:

```
var str = "&nbsp;  s dasd &nbsp; asd sad sa d  &nbsp;";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
// output
"&nbsp;  sdasdasdsadsad  &nbsp;";
```

Comment: Can you put an example of what you want?

Comment: I've added small example

Comment: `&nbsp;` is not whitespace… it becomes somewhat ambiguous what exactly you want if you consider that as whitespace too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match and capture the leading/trailing whitespaces and restore in the result with the backreferences, and remove all other whitespaces.

```js
var str = "   some text  ";
str = str.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)|\s+/g, '$1');
console.log("'",str,"'");
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(^\s+|\s+$)` - Group 1 capturing one or more whitespaces 1) at the start of string (`^\s+`) or 2) at the end of the string (`\s+$`)
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces anywhere else in the string.

The `$1` is the backreference to the capturing group contents that are inserted back into the resulting string.

To support `&nbsp;` too, use alternation, `(?:\s|&nbsp;)`:

```js
console.log("&nbsp;  s dasd &nbsp; asd sad sa d  &nbsp;".replace(/(^(?:\s|&nbsp;)+|(?:\s|&nbsp;)+$)|(?:\s|&nbsp;)+/g, '$1'));
```